# FB Spark AR - redirect to URL on click of Plane object or any other object

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I am new to spark AR, 3D and augmented world. I was reserching on spark AR and one requirement I was looking for is -

Is it possible if I have a plane in a scene( any other object), on click of which I can redirect to a URL? Or to put it in simple manner like html [anchor tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_test) or like [window.open](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is explicitly forbidden by Facebook... they don't want you to leave their platform ;)